# frustrating, irritatingly

Tags: word-choice, word-request, adverbs

A kid is playing a game interestingly. His dad/mom asks him to stop the game immediately and read books. The kids says "Okay..,I'm coming" but with little bit upset and frustrate. What are the adverbs to describe the way the responds. Which is best? Can I use *frustratingly* or  *irritatingly*?

> "Okay, I'm coming" the boy said frustratingly.

> "Okay, I'm coming" the boy said irritatingly.

> "Okay, I'm coming" the boy said ???ly.

Comment: If you say _said irritatingly_, it means he said something in a irritating way (irritating for the others); if you mean the boy was irritated, you should use _irritated_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno but I believe I can't write "Okay, I'm coming" the boy said irritated".

Comment: _"OK, I am coming," said the irritated boy._

Comment: You **can write this**, though: _"Okay, I'm coming", the boy said, irritated_. This is usually considered poor narrative style, however. It's probably better to use a different verb or slightly change the wording, eg: _"Okay, okay, I'm coming", the boy said_ or _"Okay, I'm coming", the boy {whined / groaned / snapped / moaned}_.

Comment: "said irritably" would be better than "said, irritated".

Comment: @kiamlaluno,T2E: The adverbial form for that sense is *"Okay, I'm coming", the boy said **irritatedly***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adverbs modify the verb. Adverbs ending in -ingly denote the manner in which something is done *not* how the subject feels while doing something, so double check that this is, in fact, your intention with each of these sentences.

> A kid is playing a game interestingly.

This means that the way in which the kid is *playing* is interesting. It does not mean that the kid is playing the game with great interest.

> ...the boy said frustratingly/irritatingly

Likewise, the adverbs here imply *not* that the boy is frustrated or irritated, but that the manner in which he is saying something is irritating or frustrating (presumably to his parents as they are the people to whom he is speaking).

If you want to describe that the *boy* is irritat*ed* or frustrat*ed* (as opposed to irritat*ing*- making others feel irritated) you could say frustratedly- though it would not be particularly eloquent to do so. As others have suggested in comments your best bet would be to switch the order of words:
... the boy said, irritated (or frustrated).

Or, you could choose a verb that means to say something in an irritated or frustrated manner (e.g. whined, groaned etc.).